# Intercepting requests before they go to the controller in an annotation-based Spring web-app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web-app and I'm using Spring framework. Thing is, i never properly learned to use Spring and I'm kind of lost in all this.

However, using Annotations-based controllers, I was able to create most of my app!

Now, the problem is that I would need to be able ton intercept requests before they're sent to the controllers (i need it so i can validate the user has access to the page he requests). I just spent about 5 hours searching for information about this and i actually found quite a lot, none of them worked as intended, i was never able to make my interceptor display a simple "Hello World".

Here's what I have in my *-servlet.xml (i also have the other beans definition of course):

```
<!-- this should be the class that contains the "hello world" -->
<bean id="myInterceptor" class="com.ibm.brmt.srb.admin.web.controller.TimeBasedAccessInterceptor"/>

<!-- this should "map" my interceptor no? -->
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and here is my TimeBasedAccessInterceptor class (the name isn't relevant and probably will be changed)

```
package web.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;



public class TimeBasedAccessInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");      
        }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");      
        }

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");      
        return false;
    }
}
```

the codes compile and run but what's in the TimeBasedAccessInterceptor class is never called(i even used breakpoints). can someone help me?

as requested, here is a "preview" of the way i implements the controller in the *-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="controllerName" class="web.controller.controllerNameController">  
    <property name="property1" ref="beanRef" />
    <property name="property1" ref="beanRef2"/>
</bean>
```

and in the controllerNameController.java:

```
  package web.controller;

    @Controller
    public class controllerNameController{

        @RequestMapping
        public void find(String[] enabledLvlCodes, String reset, String readRuleId, Filter filter, Errors errors,
                Model model, HttpSession session) {

       //Code goes here
       }
}
```

Comment: That should work. Can you update your answer to show your controller class, and how you're declaring it in spring?

Comment: Your @RequestMapping does not specify a URI path. Are you sure the request is reaching your controller?

Comment: yes, of this i am sure. Spring is able to automatically "create" the uri from the name of the method. If the request wasn't reaching the controller, i couldn't see the return page wich i see!

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. I suggest using a remote debugger to see what's happening in AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandlerExecutionChain, which is where the handler is combined with the "adaptedInterceptors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping looks correct.

Perhaps you have other handler mappings defined in addition to DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping (which would provide a way for your controller to be invoked via different path)?

Or perhaps your context file was not deployed properly (yes, that's a dumb suggestion but you'd be surprised how often this happens :-) )

It the answer to both is "NO", I'd suggest you put a breakpoint in `AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler()` and step through to the point where `HandlerExecutionChain` is obtained and check whether it contains your interceptor.

Comment: would:

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

be causing the problem?

Comment: absolutely. As skaffman mentioned in his comment, not having URI specified in @RequestMapping effectively renders your annotation mapping useless, causing fallback to ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping

Comment: you're right, after removing the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping and specifyin the URI in the controller, it did go into the interceptor, thanks a bunch you guys are amazing

Comment: in fact, if i just add the "interceptor" attribute to the  ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, i can keep my auto-mapping to the method name as i was using before

Comment: You certainly can, but then you should probably remove the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `@RequestMapping` annotations. Having two conflicting mapping schemes is not ideal.